# Dynamic iframe content from js response

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page where I'm dynamically creating an empty iframe. Then I need to populate the iframe content by retrieving some js-script response data. Everything works fine when I call js URL:

```
(function(d) {
    var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document,
    options = {
        objid: 152,
        key: 316541321
    },
    src = "host/widget.js",
    uri = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(options));

    iframe.id = "iframewidget";
    iframe.width = 200;
    iframe.height = 300;
    var html = '<body onload="var d=document;' +
        'd.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src=\'' + src + '\'">';
    doc.open().write(html);
    doc.close();
})(document);
```

But I need to run the widget.js with some dynamic parameter. Is there a way to pass the uri variable value to the script? I use pure JavaScript not jQuery

Comment: Just append the query string to the js file? Or what kind of parameter do you mean?

Comment: Are you sure that an iFrame is exactly what you need to create? Commonly iFrames are used to load external code into your page , for example an external HTML , PHP , etc page. You create the iFrame dynamically and then you need to pass the variables on the "src" attribute. Then the page you are loading is responsible for handling those variables. If you are planning though to render a "frame" purely from your javascript , with all the logic being "external" you should better go on creating a simple HTML Container (DIV).

Comment: @Connum how to do it? I need widget.js to use "uri" value mentioned in my code

Comment: @Strahdvonzar I'm sure I need iframe, because I make a widget that is to be placed at the customer's site. The widget contains dynamically data from my site.

I can set iframe src just after iframe created but I need my widget not block customer page loading. Besides the customer's going to place my several widgets on its page, so page speed is a critical performance issue

Comment: If you are interested in knowing for what purpose I used the subject, here is my gist: https://gist.github.com/mogilka/56a97958a6062dbb767e30261314e3d3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick modification of your code to show how its possible.

Your doc variable is the document element of the iFrame. Setting a variable on it will allow you to access it from code running within the iFrame.

https://jsfiddle.net/78gf5e8q/

```
(function(d) {
    var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document,
    options = {
        objid: 152,
        key: 316541321
    },
    //src = "host/widget.js",
    uri = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(options));
        doc.someVar = "Hello World!";
    iframe.id = "iframewidget";
    iframe.width = 200;
    iframe.height = 300;
    var html = '<body onload="var d=document;' +
        'd.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).innerHTML=\'alert(document.someVar)\'">';
      doc.open().write(html);
    doc.close();
})(document);
```

**Edit:** you were also passing in a non existent var called js into doc.open().write(js); I changed it to .write(html);

**Edit 2:** For cross domain you'll probably get "Permission Denied" on that var.